# How do I extract values from a DataSnapshot returned by 'getting' a Firebase database reference in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app using Flutter and I'm trying to read data from my Firebase Realtime Database. I'm aware of the ability to listen to events on the database, but in this case I need to manually grab data. **I'd like to be able to get a snapshot from a database reference as a `Map<String, dynamic>`, so that I can access my data via keys.**

Here's the relevant code I'm using (within a stateful widget):

```dart
late Map<String, dynamic> codes;

void getData() async {
  var snapshot = await database.ref('codes').get();
  codes = snapshot.value;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getData();
}
```

Printing `snapshot.value` displays a map as expected. Printing `snapshot.value.runtimeType` displays `_InternalLinkedHashMap`. **But** when I attempt to convert that to a `Map<String, dynamic>` it throws an error because `snapshot.value` has the type `Object?` ([stated here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html)). I'm also unable to just access data using a key for the same reason.

I tried all of the following with no success. All attempts returned errors relating to the difference in the object types.

```dart
// tried converting snapshot value to a Map
var data = snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;

// also tried generating a Map using the 'from' constructor
var data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);

// tried referencing a value straight from the snapshot value Object
var helpMe = snapshot.value['ABC123'];
```

What I was expecting was to be able to grab a snapshot and use it as a Map (because that's how the Realtime Database stores information) to access any data within the referenced node. I don't really understand why that wouldn't be exactly how it works, and if not, send me a JSON String I can decode myself.

It's been a long day, and I'm very tired, so I suspect I'm missing something very obvious. How can I convert this to a Map so I can easily access my data? And please don't tell me I'll need to iterate through the children property of the DataSnapshot to get my data, because that sounds unnecessarily painful.
Cheers!

Comment: Have you also tried simply `snapshot.value as Map;`?

Comment: I mean `var data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);`.

Comment: I believe this `var x = snapshot.value["some_child"];` is the proper syntax, but we don't know what's in 'codes' as if it has additional hierarchy, that won't work. Perhaps include the structure in the question would add some clarity. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure into the question.

Comment: @PeterKoltai that was it. I'm surprised it was that simple. Casting to a `Map<String, dynamic>` throws an error, but simply casting to a Map works. Thank you!!

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.